Select Month and Year only from DatePicker SwiftUI
I want to hide the day when a DatePicker is selected. I only want to show the month and year. I am using Swift UI.
How I am calling it:
.sheet(isPresented: $showDatePickerSheet) {
      DatePickerSheet(selectedDate: $cardExpiry)
      .presentationDetents([.medium])
}

Current DatePickerSheet
struct DatePickerSheet: View {
    @Binding var selectedDate: Date
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            DatePicker("Select Date", selection: $selectedDate, displayedComponents: .date)
                .datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())
                .padding()
                .navigationTitle("Select Date")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        Button("Done") {
                            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}

How can I create this?
I have tried modifying the displayed components to something like year and month but it does not exist.

This is not a capability of DatePicker. You will need to create your own control.

If you are looking for the wheel with only year and month components, you can get that from the UIKit. Here is the info

If you want to show only the month and years, you need to make custom view for that, otherwise you can use .datePickerStyle(.wheel), you can select date, month and year in picker style using this.
